# Fairseq Custom Model Training Error: Issues Running fairseq-train with Simple LSTM Architecture

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, sequence-to-sequence, fairseq

I am trying to train a custom sequence-to-sequence model using Fairseq's **`fairseq-train`** command. I've implemented my own SimpleLSTM architecture in Google Collab, and although Fairseq seems to detect the model correctly, it keeps throwing errors during training.

##### Data Preparation Commands:

```
!pip install fairseq
```

!git clone https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq.git

cd /content/fairseq/examples/translation

!chmod +x /content/fairseq/examples/translation/prepare-iwslt14.sh

!/content/fairseq/examples/translation/prepare-iwslt14.sh

##### Training Command:

```
!fairseq-train /content/fairseq/examples/translation/iwslt14.tokenized.de-en \
  --arch=tutorial_simple_lstm \
  --encoder-dropout=0.2 \
  --decoder-dropout=0.2 \
  --optimizer=adam \
  --lr=0.005 \
  --lr-shrink=0.5 \
  --max-tokens=12000
```

**My model:**

I've seen in other threads that the problem arose from not placing the model in the Fairseq models folder, but I have already done that with the following:

```
%%writefile /content/fairseq/fairseq/models/tutorial_simple_lstm.py

import torch.nn as nn
from fairseq import utils
from fairseq.models import FairseqEncoder

class SimpleLSTMEncoder(FairseqEncoder):
    def __init__(self, args, dictionary, embed_dim=128, hidden_dim=128, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__(dictionary)
        self.args = args
        self.embed_tokens = nn.Embedding(len(dictionary), embed_dim, padding_idx=dictionary.pad())
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embed_dim, hidden_size=hidden_dim, num_layers=1, bidirectional=False, batch_first=True)

    def forward(self, src_tokens, src_lengths):
        if self.args.left_pad_source:
            src_tokens = utils.convert_padding_direction(src_tokens, padding_idx=self.dictionary.pad(), left_to_right=True)
        x = self.embed_tokens(src_tokens)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(x, src_lengths, batch_first=True)
        _outputs, (final_hidden, _final_cell) = self.lstm(x)
        return {'final_hidden': final_hidden.squeeze(0)}

    def reorder_encoder_out(self, encoder_out, new_order):
        pass
import torch.nn as nn
from fairseq import utils
from fairseq.models import FairseqEncoder, FairseqDecoder
import torch

class SimpleLSTMEncoder(FairseqEncoder):
    def __init__(self, args, dictionary, embed_dim=128, hidden_dim=128, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__(dictionary)
        self.args = args
        self.embed_tokens = nn.Embedding(len(dictionary), embed_dim, padding_idx=dictionary.pad())
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embed_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers=1, bidirectional=False, batch_first=True)

    def forward(self, src_tokens, src_lengths):
        if self.args.left_pad_source:
            src_tokens = utils.convert_padding_direction(src_tokens, padding_idx=self.dictionary.pad(), left_to_right=True)
        x = self.embed_tokens(src_tokens)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(x, src_lengths, batch_first=True)
        _outputs, (final_hidden, _final_cell) = self.lstm(x)
        return {'final_hidden': final_hidden.squeeze(0)}

    def reorder_encoder_out(self, encoder_out, new_order):
        final_hidden = encoder_out['final_hidden']
        return {'final_hidden': final_hidden.index_select(0, new_order)}


class SimpleLSTMDecoder(FairseqDecoder):
    def __init__(self, dictionary, encoder_hidden_dim=128, embed_dim=128, hidden_dim=128, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__(dictionary)
        self.embed_tokens = nn.Embedding(len(dictionary), embed_dim, padding_idx=dictionary.pad())
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(encoder_hidden_dim + embed_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers=1, bidirectional=False)
        self.output_projection = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, len(dictionary))

    def forward(self, prev_output_tokens, encoder_out):
        bsz, tgt_len = prev_output_tokens.size()
        final_encoder_hidden = encoder_out['final_hidden']
        x = self.embed_tokens(prev_output_tokens)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = torch.cat([x, final_encoder_hidden.unsqueeze(1).expand(bsz, tgt_len, -1)], dim=2)
        initial_state = (final_encoder_hidden.unsqueeze(0), torch.zeros_like(final_encoder_hidden).unsqueeze(0))
        output, _ = self.lstm(x.transpose(0, 1), initial_state)
        x = output.transpose(0, 1)
        x = self.output_projection(x)
        return x, None

from fairseq.models import FairseqEncoderDecoderModel, register_model

@register_model('simple_lstm')
class SimpleLSTMModel(FairseqEncoderDecoderModel):

    @staticmethod
    def add_args(parser):
        parser.add_argument('--encoder-embed-dim', type=int, metavar='N')
        parser.add_argument('--encoder-hidden-dim', type=int, metavar='N')
        parser.add_argument('--encoder-dropout', type=float, default=0.1)
        parser.add_argument('--decoder-embed-dim', type=int, metavar='N')
        parser.add_argument('--decoder-hidden-dim', type=int, metavar='N')
        parser.add_argument('--decoder-dropout', type=float, default=0.1)

    @classmethod
    def build_model(cls, args, task):
        encoder = SimpleLSTMEncoder(
            args=args,
            dictionary=task.source_dictionary,
            embed_dim=args.encoder_embed_dim,
            hidden_dim=args.encoder_hidden_dim,
            dropout=args.encoder_dropout,
        )
        decoder = SimpleLSTMDecoder(
            dictionary=task.target_dictionary,
            encoder_hidden_dim=args.encoder_hidden_dim,
            embed_dim=args.decoder_embed_dim,
            hidden_dim=args.decoder_hidden_dim,
            dropout=args.decoder_dropout,
        )
        model = SimpleLSTMModel(encoder, decoder)
        print(model)
        return model

from fairseq.models import register_model_architecture

@register_model_architecture('simple_lstm', 'tutorial_simple_lstm')
def tutorial_simple_lstm(args):
    args.encoder_embed_dim = getattr(args, 'encoder_embed_dim', 256)
    args.encoder_hidden_dim = getattr(args, 'encoder_hidden_dim', 256)
    args.decoder_embed_dim = getattr(args, 'decoder_embed_dim', 256)
    args.decoder_hidden_dim = getattr(args, 'decoder_hidden_dim', 256)
```

**The Error:**

```
2023-09-16 11:37:17.444106: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-09-16 11:37:18.331492: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2023-09-16 11:37:19 | INFO | numexpr.utils | NumExpr defaulting to 2 threads.
2023-09-16 11:37:20 | INFO | fairseq.tasks.text_to_speech | Please install tensorboardX: pip install tensorboardX
usage: fairseq-train
       [-h]
       [--no-progress-bar]
       [--log-interval LOG_INTERVAL]
       [--log-format {json,none,simple,tqdm}]
       [--log-file LOG_FILE]
       [--aim-repo AIM_REPO]
       [--aim-run-hash AIM_RUN_HASH]
       [--tensorboard-logdir TENSORBOARD_LOGDIR]
       [--wandb-project WANDB_PROJECT]
       [--azureml-logging]
       [--seed SEED]
       [--cpu]
       [--tpu]
       [--bf16]
       [--memory-efficient-bf16]
       [--fp16]
       [--memory-efficient-fp16]
       [--fp16-no-flatten-grads]
       [--fp16-init-scale FP16_INIT_SCALE]
       [--fp16-scale-window FP16_SCALE_WINDOW]
       [--fp16-scale-tolerance FP16_SCALE_TOLERANCE]
       [--on-cpu-convert-precision]
       [--min-loss-scale MIN_LOSS_SCALE]
       [--threshold-loss-scale THRESHOLD_LOSS_SCALE]
       [--amp]
       [--amp-batch-retries AMP_BATCH_RETRIES]
       [--amp-init-scale AMP_INIT_SCALE]
       [--amp-scale-window AMP_SCALE_WINDOW]
       [--user-dir USER_DIR]
       [--empty-cache-freq EMPTY_CACHE_FREQ]
       [--all-gather-list-size ALL_GATHER_LIST_SIZE]
       [--model-parallel-size MODEL_PARALLEL_SIZE]
       [--quantization-config-path QUANTIZATION_CONFIG_PATH]
       [--profile]
       [--reset-logging]
       [--suppress-crashes]
       [--use-plasma-view]
       [--plasma-path PLASMA_PATH]
       [--criterion {adaptive_loss,composite_loss,cross_entropy,ctc,fastspeech2,hubert,label_smoothed_cross_entropy,latency_augmented_label_smoothed_cross_entropy,label_smoothed_cross_entropy_with_alignment,label_smoothed_cross_entropy_with_ctc,legacy_masked_lm_loss,masked_lm,model,nat_loss,sentence_prediction,sentence_prediction_adapters,sentence_ranking,tacotron2,speech_to_unit,speech_to_spectrogram,speech_unit_lm_criterion,wav2vec,vocab_parallel_cross_entropy}]
       [--tokenizer {moses,nltk,space}]
       [--bpe {byte_bpe,bytes,characters,fastbpe,gpt2,bert,hf_byte_bpe,sentencepiece,subword_nmt}]
       [--optimizer {adadelta,adafactor,adagrad,adam,adamax,composite,cpu_adam,lamb,nag,sgd}]
       [--lr-scheduler {cosine,fixed,inverse_sqrt,manual,pass_through,polynomial_decay,reduce_lr_on_plateau,step,tri_stage,triangular}]
       [--scoring {bert_score,sacrebleu,bleu,chrf,meteor,wer}]
       [--task TASK]
       [--num-workers NUM_WORKERS]
       [--skip-invalid-size-inputs-valid-test]
       [--max-tokens MAX_TOKENS]
       [--batch-size BATCH_SIZE]
       [--required-batch-size-multiple REQUIRED_BATCH_SIZE_MULTIPLE]
       [--required-seq-len-multiple REQUIRED_SEQ_LEN_MULTIPLE]
       [--dataset-impl {raw,lazy,cached,mmap,fasta,huffman}]
       [--data-buffer-size DATA_BUFFER_SIZE]
       [--train-subset TRAIN_SUBSET]
       [--valid-subset VALID_SUBSET]
       [--combine-valid-subsets]
       [--ignore-unused-valid-subsets]
       [--validate-interval VALIDATE_INTERVAL]
       [--validate-interval-updates VALIDATE_INTERVAL_UPDATES]
       [--validate-after-updates VALIDATE_AFTER_UPDATES]
       [--fixed-validation-seed FIXED_VALIDATION_SEED]
       [--disable-validation]
       [--max-tokens-valid MAX_TOKENS_VALID]
       [--batch-size-valid BATCH_SIZE_VALID]
       [--max-valid-steps MAX_VALID_STEPS]
       [--curriculum CURRICULUM]
       [--gen-subset GEN_SUBSET]
       [--num-shards NUM_SHARDS]
       [--shard-id SHARD_ID]
       [--grouped-shuffling]
       [--update-epoch-batch-itr UPDATE_EPOCH_BATCH_ITR]
       [--update-ordered-indices-seed]
       [--distributed-world-size DISTRIBUTED_WORLD_SIZE]
       [--distributed-num-procs DISTRIBUTED_NUM_PROCS]
       [--distributed-rank DISTRIBUTED_RANK]
       [--distributed-backend DISTRIBUTED_BACKEND]
       [--distributed-init-method DISTRIBUTED_INIT_METHOD]
       [--distributed-port DISTRIBUTED_PORT]
       [--device-id DEVICE_ID]
       [--distributed-no-spawn]
       [--ddp-backend {c10d,fully_sharded,legacy_ddp,no_c10d,pytorch_ddp,slowmo}]
       [--ddp-comm-hook {none,fp16}]
       [--bucket-cap-mb BUCKET_CAP_MB]
       [--fix-batches-to-gpus]
       [--find-unused-parameters]
       [--gradient-as-bucket-view]
       [--fast-stat-sync]
       [--heartbeat-timeout HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT]
       [--broadcast-buffers]
       [--slowmo-momentum SLOWMO_MOMENTUM]
       [--slowmo-base-algorithm SLOWMO_BASE_ALGORITHM]
       [--localsgd-frequency LOCALSGD_FREQUENCY]
       [--nprocs-per-node NPROCS_PER_NODE]
       [--pipeline-model-parallel]
       [--pipeline-balance PIPELINE_BALANCE]
       [--pipeline-devices PIPELINE_DEVICES]
       [--pipeline-chunks PIPELINE_CHUNKS]
       [--pipeline-encoder-balance PIPELINE_ENCODER_BALANCE]
       [--pipeline-encoder-devices PIPELINE_ENCODER_DEVICES]
       [--pipeline-decoder-balance PIPELINE_DECODER_BALANCE]
       [--pipeline-decoder-devices PIPELINE_DECODER_DEVICES]
       [--pipeline-checkpoint {always,never,except_last}]
       [--zero-sharding {none,os}]
       [--no-reshard-after-forward]
       [--fp32-reduce-scatter]
       [--cpu-offload]
       [--use-sharded-state]
       [--not-fsdp-flatten-parameters]
       [--arch ARCH]
       [--max-epoch MAX_EPOCH]
       [--max-update MAX_UPDATE]
       [--stop-time-hours STOP_TIME_HOURS]
       [--clip-norm CLIP_NORM]
       [--sentence-avg]
       [--update-freq UPDATE_FREQ]
       [--lr LR]
       [--stop-min-lr STOP_MIN_LR]
       [--use-bmuf]
       [--skip-remainder-batch]
       [--save-dir SAVE_DIR]
       [--restore-file RESTORE_FILE]
       [--continue-once CONTINUE_ONCE]
       [--finetune-from-model FINETUNE_FROM_MODEL]
       [--reset-dataloader]
       [--reset-lr-scheduler]
       [--reset-meters]
       [--reset-optimizer]
       [--optimizer-overrides OPTIMIZER_OVERRIDES]
       [--save-interval SAVE_INTERVAL]
       [--save-interval-updates SAVE_INTERVAL_UPDATES]
       [--keep-interval-updates KEEP_INTERVAL_UPDATES]
       [--keep-interval-updates-pattern KEEP_INTERVAL_UPDATES_PATTERN]
       [--keep-last-epochs KEEP_LAST_EPOCHS]
       [--keep-best-checkpoints KEEP_BEST_CHECKPOINTS]
       [--no-save]
       [--no-epoch-checkpoints]
       [--no-last-checkpoints]
       [--no-save-optimizer-state]
       [--best-checkpoint-metric BEST_CHECKPOINT_METRIC]
       [--maximize-best-checkpoint-metric]
       [--patience PATIENCE]
       [--checkpoint-suffix CHECKPOINT_SUFFIX]
       [--checkpoint-shard-count CHECKPOINT_SHARD_COUNT]
       [--load-checkpoint-on-all-dp-ranks]
       [--write-checkpoints-asynchronously]
       [--store-ema]
       [--ema-decay EMA_DECAY]
       [--ema-start-update EMA_START_UPDATE]
       [--ema-seed-model EMA_SEED_MODEL]
       [--ema-update-freq EMA_UPDATE_FREQ]
       [--ema-fp32]
fairseq-train: error: argument --arch/-a: invalid choice: 'tutorial_simple_lstm' (choose from 's2t_berard', 's2t_berard_256_3_3', 's2t_berard_512_3_2', 's2t_berard_512_5_3', 'transformer_tiny', 'transformer', 'transformer_iwslt_de_en', 'transformer_wmt_en_de', 'transformer_vaswani_wmt_en_de_big', 'transformer_vaswani_wmt_en_fr_big', 'transformer_wmt_en_de_big', 'transformer_wmt_en_de_big_t2t', 'convtransformer', 'convtransformer_espnet', 's2t_transformer', 's2t_transformer_s', 's2t_transformer_xs', 's2t_transformer_sp', 's2t_transformer_m', 's2t_transformer_mp', 's2t_transformer_l', 's2t_transformer_lp', 'wav2vec', 'wav2vec2', 'wav2vec_ctc', 'wav2vec_seq2seq', 'xm_transformer', 's2t_conformer', 'fconv', 'fconv_iwslt_de_en', 'fconv_wmt_en_ro', 'fconv_wmt_en_de', 'fconv_wmt_en_fr', 'tacotron_2', 'tts_transformer', 'fastspeech2', 'lstm', 'lstm_wiseman_iwslt_de_en', 'lstm_luong_wmt_en_de', 'lstm_lm', 'fconv_lm', 'fconv_lm_dauphin_wikitext103', 'fconv_lm_dauphin_gbw', 'hubert', 'hubert_ctc', 'lightconv', 'lightconv_iwslt_de_en', 'lightconv_wmt_en_de', 'lightconv_wmt_en_de_big', 'lightconv_wmt_en_fr_big', 'lightconv_wmt_zh_en_big', 'lightconv_lm', 'lightconv_lm_gbw', 'fconv_self_att', 'fconv_self_att_wp', 'nonautoregressive_transformer', 'nonautoregressive_transformer_wmt_en_de', 'nacrf_transformer', 'iterative_nonautoregressive_transformer', 'iterative_nonautoregressive_transformer_wmt_en_de', 'cmlm_transformer', 'cmlm_transformer_wmt_en_de', 'levenshtein_transformer', 'levenshtein_transformer_wmt_en_de', 'levenshtein_transformer_vaswani_wmt_en_de_big', 'levenshtein_transformer_wmt_en_de_big', 'insertion_transformer', 'transformer_lm', 'transformer_lm_big', 'transformer_lm_baevski_wiki103', 'transformer_lm_wiki103', 'transformer_lm_baevski_gbw', 'transformer_lm_gbw', 'transformer_lm_gpt', 'transformer_lm_gpt2_small', 'transformer_lm_gpt2_tiny', 'transformer_lm_gpt2_medium', 'transformer_lm_gpt2_big', 'transformer_lm_gpt2_big_wide', 'transformer_lm_gpt2_bigger', 'transformer_lm_gpt3_small', 'transformer_lm_gpt3_medium', 'transformer_lm_gpt3_large', 'transformer_lm_gpt3_xl', 'transformer_lm_gpt3_2_7', 'transformer_lm_gpt3_6_7', 'transformer_lm_gpt3_13', 'transformer_lm_gpt3_175', 'transformer_ulm', 'transformer_ulm_big', 'transformer_ulm_tiny', 'roberta', 'roberta_prenorm', 'roberta_base', 'roberta_large', 'xlm', 'roberta_enc_dec', 'transformer_from_pretrained_xlm', 'transformer_align', 'transformer_wmt_en_de_big_align', 'xmod_base_13', 'xmod_base_30', 'xmod_base_60', 'xmod_base_75', 'xmod_base', 'xmod_large_prenorm', 'bart_large', 'bart_base', 'mbart_large', 'mbart_base', 'mbart_base_wmt20', 's2ut_transformer', 's2ut_transformer_fisher', 's2spect_transformer', 's2spect_transformer_fisher', 's2ut_conformer', 'masked_lm', 'bert_base', 'bert_large', 'xlm_base', 'multilingual_transformer', 'multilingual_transformer_iwslt_de_en', 'hf_gpt2', 'hf_gpt2_medium', 'hf_gpt2_large', 'hf_gpt2_xl', 'dummy_model', 'model_parallel_roberta', 'model_parallel_roberta_v1', 'model_parallel_roberta_postnorm', 'model_parallel_roberta_base', 'model_parallel_roberta_large', 'transformer_iwslt_de_en_pipeline_parallel', 'transformer_wmt_en_de_big_pipeline_parallel', 'transformer_lm_megatron', 'transformer_lm_megatron_11b')
```

I believe the error could either be in the execution environment since it's Google Colab, in the installed libraries, or in the model code itself which may not be well implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution:

```
!git clone https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq.git
%cd fairseq
!pip install --editable .
```

Make the repository editable.